# JDBC (MS SQL) Disable all tranactions to execute sp_replicationdboption statement

Tags: java, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to execute the `sp_replicationdboption` stored proc to disable replication on a DB.  But I get an exception:

> The procedure 'sp_replicationdboption' cannot be executed within a transaction.

I'm new to JDBC and have tried to google for a way to completely disable transactions for executing my Statement, but could only find a lot of content about disabling auto-commit, which is not what im looking for.

How can I turn off transactions completely so the JDBC driver does not implicitly start a transaction for the statement I want to execute?

Comment: If the procedure can't be run in a transaction then _enabling_ auto commit (`Connection.setAutocommit(true)`) **is** the solution

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I will give it a go and see if that works :)